# Update a table based in some conditions

Tags: sql, nested

I need to update the `DataEHoraInicialDoFeedback` column with the value from the `DataEHoraInicial` column, where the `DescricaoDoFeedback` is not empty (the field has no null values) and `DataEHoraInicialDoFeedback` is null or `DataEHoraInicialDoFeedback` is empty and `StatusDoFeedback` has the value `com Sucesso`

```
UPDATE GestaoDeAlertas
SET GestaoDeAlertas.DataEHoraInicialDoFeedback = GestaoDeAlertas.DataEHoraInicial
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM GestaoDeAlertas
    WHERE DescricaoDoFeedback <> ''
    AND (DataEHoraInicialDoFeedback IS NULL OR DataEHoraInicialDoFeedback= '')
    AND StatusDoFeedback= 'com Sucesso'
)
```

In my tests (I have duplicated the table) the above update is updating all rows, as if it is ignoring the where clause.

Comment: Forget the subquery.  Just put all those conditions in your where clause.

Comment: What is your RDBMS (SQL Flavor)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query says:

> If there is **at least one row** in the entire table that satisfies
>   the specified condition, then do the update (regardless of the values in the **current** row).

I believe that `Dan Bracuk` already gave you the right advice (see his comment): use direct `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks `Dan Bracuk` and `PM`